# Lua String concatenation

Tags: string, lua, string-concatenation

I am working on Lua and I have this kind of code

```
MapMessage(Process["ks.MSH"][1], MsgIn, mg)
MapEvent(Process["ks.EVN"][1], MsgIn, mg)
MapPatient(Process["ks.PID"][1], MsgIn, mg)
MapVisit(Process["ks.PV1"][1],MsgIn,mg)
```

In above statements, MapMessage, MapEvent, MapPatient, MapVisit are the functions and ks.MSH, ks.EVN, ks.PID, ks.PV1 are the tables in the database.
Now, I want to automate a part of this process using gmatch function provided in lua and I have this so far

```
for u in string.gmatch(S, "([^,%s]+)"), 1 do
     l[k] = u 
    _G["Map"..l[k]](Process["ks[l[k]]"][1], R[1])
     k=k+1
   end
```

but the concatenation part in the third line of above code is not really making it ks.MSH, ks.PID, ks.PV1 e.t.c, so please suggest what needs to be there in place of `(Process["ks[l[k]]"][1]`to get s.MSH, ks.PID, ks.PV1 e.t.c

Comment: `_G["Map"..l[k]](Process[ks[l[k]]][1], R[1])`

Comment: @Egor, No since I have double quotes around as well, it's not working, Please have a closer look , (Process["ks.PV1"][1],MsgIn,mg) , This is what exactly I need

Comment: Can you show what you have in `S`?

Comment: @hjpotter92: In S, I have "MSH, PID, PV1, EVN" e.t.c, depending on events, sometimes I have all these 4 , rest of the time any 3 or 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your string contains `"MSH, PID, PV1, EVN"`, you'd have to use a hash-table or a lookup table. The program would be something like this:

```
S = "MSH, PID, PV1, EVN"
tLookup = {
    MSH = "Message",
    EVN = "Event",
    PID = "Patient",
    PV1 = "Visit",
}

for u in S:gmatch "([^,%s]+)" do
    sNameOfFunction = tLoopup[u]
    _G[ "Map"..sNameOfFunction ] ( Process["ks."..u][1], MsgIn, mg )
     k=k+1
end
```

---

Or even something like this:

```
S = "MSH, PID, PV1, EVN"
tLookup = {
    MSH = _G.MapMessage,
    EVN = _G.MapEvent,
    PID = _G.MapPatient,
    PV1 = _G.MapVisit,
}

for u in S:gmatch "([^,%s]+)" do
    tLoopup[u] ( Process["ks."..u][1], MsgIn, mg )
    k = k+1
end
```

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92: by the way, this code worked from me, I figured oit as soon as you suggested about S .Here is the code that worked:ks = {MSH = "ks.MSH", EVN = "ks.EVN", PID = "ks.PID", PV1 = "ks.PV1", PV2 = "ks.PV2"}
S = tostring(R[1].AllSegmentsList)
 l = {}
k = 1
for u in string.gmatch(S, "([^,%s]+)") do
 l[k] = u 
 _G["Map"..l[k]](Process[ks[l[k]]][1], MsgIn, mg)
   k=k+1

Comment: @Simrankaur You can mark the solution as selected/answer and the question will appear as such in the questions list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what finally worked, thanks Egor and hjpotter92 :)

```
ks = {MSH = "ks.MSH", EVN = "ks.EVN", PID = "ks.PID", PV1 = "ks.PV1", PV2 = "ks.PV2"}
S = tostring(R[1].AllSegmentsList)
 l = {}
k = 1
for u in string.gmatch(S, "([^,%s]+)") do
 l[k] = u 
 _G["Map"..l[k]](Process[ks[l[k]]][1], MsgIn, mg)
   k=k+1
end
```

Comment: Consider to upvote (and even accept) an answer that has proven useful.